# Error copying files

Tags: python, copy, shutil

I'm trying to write a short Python script that will copy all files from a directory with a certain extension and place them in a different folder. Here is the script:

```
import os, shutil

source = "C:\\TCR_Calgary\\projects\\"

destination = "C:\\TCR_Calgary\\reference\\my_code\\city_of_calgary_scripts\\"

extension = ".py"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source):
    for file in files:
        if file.lower().endswith(extension):
            shutil.copy2(file, destination)
```

This is the exception I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/TCR_Calgary/reference/my_code/city_of_calgary_scripts/python_script_copier.py", line 13, in <module>
    shutil.copy2(file, destination)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python26\lib\shutil.py", line 99, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python26\lib\shutil.py", line 47, in copyfile
    raise Error, "`%s` and `%s` are the same file" % (src, dst)
shutil.Error: `AnnoMover.py` and `C:\TCR_Calgary\reference\my_code\city_of_calgary_scripts\AnnoMover.py` are the same file
```

I'm confused because AnnoMover.py is not in the destination folder. In my mind, the original file and its copy would be "the same" although their paths would not. There's clearly something I'm not understanding here. Any help is much appreciated!

Version: Python 2.6
Interpeter: PyCharm Community Edition 3.4
OS: Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

The exception message could be a little clearer, but the last line should be `shutil.copy2(os.path.join(source, file), destination)` so that the source is fully qualified.

Comment: Thanks! This didn't quite work for me (because the files to be copied are in sub-folders within source) but it did point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work:

```
import os, shutil

source = r"C:\TCR_Calgary\projects"

destination = r"C:\TCR_Calgary\reference\my_code\city_of_calgary_scripts"

extension = ".py"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source):
    for file in files:
        if file.lower().endswith(extension):
            file_path = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(root, file))
            shutil.copy2(file_path, destination)
```